# How do I get the username from the user ID?

Tags: users, 8

I want to print the username knowing just the user ID. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Your title is about 7, and question body about 8. Voting to close as unclear now.

Comment: $user = User::load($uid);
$userName = $user->getUsername();

Comment: In Drupal 8 - $current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
$user_name = $current_user->getAccountName();

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [user_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/8) or `\Drupal\user\Entity\User::load` to do this. Below code will provide the solution

```
 public function content() {
     $account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load('uid'); // pass your uid
     $name = $account->getUsername();
     drupal_set_message($name);
 }
```

`$name` gives the username of the user.

Comment: link for user_load is depreciated, 
you should probably use Entity::load https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Aload/8.2.x

Comment: Using `$account->getDisplayName()` will help ensure you get any altered value of the username.

Comment: /Drupal/Core/Session/AccountInterface::getUsername() is deprecated in Drupal 8.0.0, will be removed before Drupal 9.0.0. Use /Drupal/Core/Session/AccountInterface::getAccountName() or /Drupal/user/UserInterface::getDisplayName() instead. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2572493

Answer (score 7):

In D8, if you don't know the uid, you can do this:

```
function test_user_login(\Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account) {
   $account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
   $user = $account->get('name')->value;
   drupal_set_message($user, 'status'); }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to get the user's name programmatically

```
$account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1); // pass your uid    
//1 
drupal_set_message($account->name->value);    
//2
drupal_set_message($account->get("name")->value);    
//3
drupal_set_message($account->getUsername());
//4
drupal_set_message($account->name->getValue()[0][value]);
```

Comment: in drupal 9, getUsername() was changed to getAccountName();

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`user_load($uid);`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load/7)
This will return a fully loaded User object(in D7).

```
$user = user_load($uid);
print $user->name;
```

This should print the user name.

Comment: It throws webiste encountered error after adding this lines. I think above code works for D7

Comment: Question is tagged [8].